# Prove that $A_n$ is a Normal subgroup of $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups

I know how to prove that $A_n$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ but i do not know how to prove this using the index.

Comment: What is the additional properties one needs to show a subgroup is normal?

Comment: HINT: $A_n$ is by definition the kernel of some homomorphism (the homomorphism mapping every permutation to its sign), hence it is obviously normal.

Answer (score 5):

The index is $2$ so automatically left cosets will coincide with right cosets.

If $\sigma\in A_n$ then $\sigma A_n=A_n=A_n\sigma$.

If $\sigma\notin A_n$ then $\sigma A_n=S_n\setminus A_n=A_n\sigma$.

Comment: can you provide me with the formal proof

Comment: This IS  a formal proof.

Comment: I agree with @Crostul.